# Composer require phpoffice/phpexcel not installing

Tags: php, shell, magento, ssh, phpoffice

Basically I'm trying to execute;

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

And I get;

```
Using version ^1.8 for phpoffice/phpexcel
./composer.json has been updated


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                
  Type error: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1::  
  initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void  
  , none returned
```

Note: I am doing this within a Magento installation if that makes any difference.